# Linear algebra identity proof by induction

Tags: linear-algebra, induction

I want to prove that $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}^n=\begin{pmatrix}1 & n\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}, n=1,2,3\dots$
by induction, I've come this far:

Basis:

$U_1:\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}^1=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$.

Inductive step: We then assume that $U_k$ is true

$U_k:\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}^k=\begin{pmatrix}1 & k\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$

Then

$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}^{k+1}=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}^k+\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$

I'm not sure if the last part is right and how to proceed...

Comment: The $+$ should be a $\cdot$ in the last line.

Comment: @JulianKuelshammer But whats the (induction-wise) argument for multiplying the matrix on the left side of U_k?

Comment: matrix multiplication is associative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}^{k+1}=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}^k+\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$
This will be
$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}^{k+1}=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}^k.\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$
$$=\begin{pmatrix}1 & k\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}.\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$
$$=\begin{pmatrix}1 & k+1\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: So should it be a + or $\cdot$ in the last line as noted in the comments underneath the question?

Comment: It's been a long time since linear algebra but it's definitely the dot and not the plus.